# how to include an entity join in sonata bundle admin list view

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

related code:

in services.yml

```
sonata.admin.domain:
        class: MyBundle\AdminBundle\Admin\MyAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Domains", label: "Domains" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundle\ServiceBundle\Entity\MyEntity
            - ~
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyOtherBundle]]
```

in my admin controller:

```
 protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('domain')
            ->add('user.email')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                             'actions'  => array(
                                                 'show' => array())));

    }
```

which errors in:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user
```

to describe the problem further, i have a table that has a user_id column, and i want to be able to include the users email address (using fos user bundle) in that same list with that table. i've tried custom query with no luck also. thanks ahead of time

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted for asking this question. I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is official documentation about list view definition :

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html

and

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html

if you have a user_id within you entity, i guess your entity is an override of fosUserBundle, right ?

so normally you directly access from the list field definition like this :

```
->add('user.email') // user is you entity object
```

otherwise if it s a standalone entity with a user_id, you might have a relationship between this entity and the entity which owns your fosuserbundle object, and like in the above list field definition , you should normally access the object email.

Comment: I've read those over and over again, and from the past day of debugging this, I realized that the entity itself didn't have the annotation mapping correctly. currently the user_id is just a bigint standalone user_id with no ORM mapping. is there still an easy way to do it? i'm afraid that if i delete that userId and put in a one to many user mapping that it will break large parts of the existing application.

Comment: it will surely break your existing data ... but you can fix this by creating another column which is mapped to your user entity, then loop through every object to update them correctly according to you user_id. finally you ll be able to remove your bigint column

Comment: Going to accept this as the answer. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: So I actually found a better way to do this without having to change my core entities for the application, I was able to just create a view in postgresql, and then create an entity that maps to that view. the only drawback i did have after that was that views in postgresql can't have a primary key, and doctrine expects one, so I ended up just using one of the unique fields in the view as @ORM\Id and that caused doctrine to stop complaining :)

Comment: Sal views aren t supported by doctrine. It means that next time you Will update your schéma, the view will be destroyed and You Will have to recreate it

Comment: we don't use doctrine to update the schema at all, so it's okay for our use case, but i'm glad you wrote that for anyone else coming across this thread.